# What kind of set system is defined to have this property?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, matroids

Let $E$ be a set, and $F \in \mathcal P(E)$ has the following property:

For every $x\in E$ and $Y,Z\in F$ with $x\notin Y\cup Z$, there exists $X\in F$ with $(Y\cap Z)\cup\{x\}\subseteq X$.

I wonder if this property has a name? What kind of set system is defined to have the property?

[An example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Hyperplanes) is from matroid theory:

> The family $\mathcal{H}$ of hyperplanes of a matroid has the following properties, which may be taken as yet another axiomatization of matroids:[4]
>
> - There do not exist distinct sets $X$ and $Y \in \mathcal{H}$ with $X\subset Y$. That is, the hyperplanes form a Sperner family.
> - For every $x\in E$ and $Y,Z\in\mathcal{H}$ with $x\notin Y\cup Z$, there exists $X\in\mathcal{H}$ with $(Y\cap Z)\cup\{x\}\subseteq X$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is known as one of the two hyperplane axioms. For reference, please see Matroid Theory by D.J.A. Welsh, pages 39-40. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=QL2iYMBLpFwC) is the link to it on google books (and pages 39-40 are freely available in the preview). The book then seems to go on to cover some other systems with this property, but the next few pages are not freely available.